# How to avoid OutOfMemoryException while loading large chunks of data from a database?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2000, out-of-memory

Say, we have a table with some large `text` field containg jpg-files' binary data. The task is to get those files from a database on disk. So, at first I decided to do the following:

```
MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext();
foreach(ImageTable t in dc.ImageTable.OrderBy(i=>i.Id))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(string.Concat(t.Name,".jpg"), FileMode.CreateNew), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)))
    {
          writer.Write(t.Data);
          writer.Close();
    }
}
```

But as soon as the table had about 20 thousand of rows, in a while I got an `OutOfMemoryException`.

In the end, to avoid loading of all the rows into one datacontext I did the following:

```
MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext();
foreach(int id in dc.ImageTable.OrderBy(i=>i.Id).Select(i=>i.Id))
{
     using (MyDataContext _dc = new MyDataContext())
     {
           ImageTable t = _dc.ImageTable.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
           using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(string.Concat(t.Name,".jpg"), FileMode.CreateNew), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)))
           {
                writer.Write(t.Data);
                writer.Close();
           }
      }
}
```

So each row is loaded by a separate datacontext...no memory problem left!
But surely it's not the best approach to do the task.

Could anyone suggest something?

Comment: Creating a new data context is a lightweight operation, so it's not a very big deal.  That being said, turning off object tracking as spender mentioned is the right solution.

Comment: Firstly, what for do you need 20 000 rows of data at once??? Secondly, WHY you store jpgs in a db? The fact "you can" doesn't mean "you should".

Comment: I don't store pictures there...some corporate software does...my task was to get them out from the db to import into some other system...So, obviously all the lines had to be exported to disk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try switching off [object tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.objecttrackingenabled.aspx):

```
_dc.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. If it  already works: resolving memory issue, with performance that fits the needs of your application, **it's a good solution**.
2. If you're still not satisfied with the results, you *may* think about leaving `linq to sql` and look on `raw SQL` use [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with *readonly*, *forward only* cursor, to get maximum efficiency in read operation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Linq-To-Sql has ramifications on performance, but when used properly has little bearing on out of memory errors.

Comment: @Tigran Though it was a one-time task and the task is really done, I tested it with ObjectTrackingEnabled = false...and that was it! When I was solving my memory problem, I (completely forgot about ObjectTracking) understood that a simlpe DataReader would do the trick, but anyway it was quicker for me to do it with L2S. Thank you!